# Excel VBA: On Error Goto statement not working inside For-Loop

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop, error-handling

I'm trying to cycle through a table in excel. The first three columns of this table have text headings, the rest of them have dates as headings. I want to assign those dates, sequentially, to a Date-type variable, and then perform some operations based on the date

To do this I am using a foreach loop on myTable.ListColumns. Since the first three columns do not have date headers, I have tried to set the loop up so that, if there is an error assigning the header string to the date-type variable, the loop goes straight to the next column

This seems to work for the first column. However, when the second column's header is 'assigned' to the date-type variable, the macro encounters an error even though it is within an error-handling block

```
Dim myCol As ListColumn
For Each myCol In myTable.ListColumns
    On Error GoTo NextCol

    Dim myDate As Date
    myDate = CDate(myCol.Name)

    On Error GoTo 0

    'MORE CODE HERE

NextCol:
    On Error GoTo 0
Next myCol
```

To reiterate, the error is thrown on the second round of the loop, at the statement

```
myDate = CDate(myCol.Name)
```

Can anyone explain why the On Error statement stops working?

Comment: Rather than using an error as your control structure, maybe an IF with an IsDate function would be more suitable in this scenario?

Comment: If you are "blindly" handling the error - rather than taking specific action on an error type - then you should just use an `On Error Resume Next` outside your loop. At the moment you are using error handling afresh on each column.

Comment: @brettdj, I don't think you can just resume next. The whole idea is to skip over the "more code here" code if the date conversion fails. So you need to go into a handler so that you can resume to a specific line. In addition, you only want the handler enabled for the date conversion, not the entire loop body.

Comment: @paxdiablo On reflection I agree. I would like to see 'more code here'.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

With the code as shown, you're actually still considered to be *within* the error handling routine when you strike the `next` statement.

That means that subsequent error handlers are not allowed until you resume from the current one.

A better architecture would be:

```
    Dim myCol As ListColumn
    For Each myCol In myTable.ListColumns
        On Error GoTo ErrCol
        Dim myDate As Date
        myDate = CDate(myCol.Name)
        On Error GoTo 0
        ' MORE CODE HERE '
NextCol:
    Next myCol
    Exit Sub ' or something '

ErrCol:
    Resume NextCol
```

This clearly delineates error handling from regular code and ensures that the currently executing error handler finishes before you try to set up another handler.

[This site](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm) has a good description of the problem:

---

**Error Handling Blocks And On Error Goto**

An error handling block, also called an error handler, is a section of code to which execution is tranferred via a `On Error Goto <label>:` statement. This code should be designed either to fix the problem and resume execution in the main code block or to terminate execution of the procedure. You can't use the `On Error Goto <label>:` statement merely skip over lines. For example, the following code will not work properly:

```
    On Error GoTo Err1:
    Debug.Print 1 / 0
    ' more code
Err1:
    On Error GoTo Err2:
    Debug.Print 1 / 0
    ' more code
Err2:
```

When the first error is raised, execution transfers to the line following `Err1:`. The error hander is still active when the second error occurs, and therefore the second error is not trapped by the `On Error` statement.

Comment: "A better architecture" would be... a better error handling technique than skipping over errors :)

Comment: @enderland: well, yes, that may be preferable, but "Needs must when the devil vomits into your kettle" :-)

Comment: @brettdj, I'm not so sure of that. You only want the error handler enabled during the data conversion, _not_ in the bit that says "more code here".

Comment: @paxdiablo You make a fair point. Although I think it would make more sense to have error handling on through-out, and then test for the error condition triggered to judge how to handle it. +1 btw

Answer (score 8):

You need to add `resume` of some sorts in your error handling code to indicate the error handling is over. Otherwise, the first error handler is still active and you are never "resolved."

See http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm (specifically the heading "Error Handling Blocks And On Error Goto" and following section)

Answer (score 7):

Follow-up to paxdiablo's accepted answer. This is possible, allowing two error traps in the same sub, one after the other :

```
Public Sub test()
    On Error GoTo Err1:
    Debug.Print 1 / 0
    ' more code
Err1:
    On Error GoTo -1     ' clears the active error handler
    On Error GoTo Err2:  ' .. so we can set up another
    Debug.Print 1 / 0
    ' more code
Err2:
    MsgBox "Got here safely"
End Sub
```

Using `On Error GoTo -1` cancels the active error handler and allows another to be set up (and `err.clear` doesn't do this!). Whether this is a good idea or not is left as an exercise for the reader, but it works!

Comment: Thanks. Was so helpful. Actually, on the loops, you need to reset the error handling...

Answer (score 1):

change it to On error goto -1, instead

```
Dim myCol As ListColumn
For Each myCol In myTable.ListColumns
    On Error GoTo NextCol

    Dim myDate As Date
    myDate = CDate(myCol.Name)

    On Error GoTo 0

    'MORE CODE HERE

NextCol:
    On Error GoTo -1
Next myCol
```

Answer (score 0):

Clearing all property settings of the Err object is not the same as resetting the error handler.

Try this:

```
Sub TestErr()
Dim i As Integer
Dim x As Double
    On Error GoTo NextLoop
    For i = 1 To 2
10:     x = i / 0
NextLoop:
        If Err <> 0 Then
            Err.Clear
            Debug.Print "Cleared i=" & i
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

You'll notice the just like the OP, it will catch the error properly when `i =1` but it will fail on line 10 when `i = 2`, even though we used `Err.Clear`

Answer (score 0):

Dim ws As worksheets

For Each myCol In myTable.ListColumns

```
On Error GoTo endbit

Dim myDate As Date

myDate = CDate(myCol.Name)

On Error GoTo 0
'MORE CODE HERE
```

endbit:
Resume NextCol

NextCol:
'    Next myCol
Exit Sub ' or something '