# Different computers handling "On Error Resume Next" differently?

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code:

```
Sub test()
    On Error GoTo Label
    Debug.Print 1 / 0
    Exit Sub
Label:
    MsgBox "Infinity!"
End Sub
```

If I run this code on my laptop, I get "Infinity", as I expected. However... When I run it on my desktop, excel throws an error message `Runtime error 11 ... Division by zero`

Has anyone ever experienced this before? It's almost like my Excel desktop client has just 'forgotton' how to handle errors...

Comment: I think you might want to change the title of your question so it lines up with what you want to know

Comment: Also, see here https://stackoverflow.com/a/11999000/2727437

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 I'm afraid the linked stack overflow post is something I have already visited and does not help. As said, 2 computers are handling the same code differently... That being said, this may not be a question for stack overflow as it isn't code related...

Comment: Could it be different versions of Excel or Windows? divide by 0 is captured at the CPU level, I do know that much

Comment: @HilaDG Hmm.. Well my laptop is Win10 and Desktop is Win7, so that's a possibility. If I had another Win10/Win7 computer I'd test it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely this is due to different settings in your VB editor under

*Tools>>Options>>General>>Error Trapping*

If set to "Break on all errors" then that's what it does...

Comment: Ergh... You're right. For goodness sakes. Desktop: `Break on All Errors` v.s. Laptop: `Break on Unhandled Errors`. I assume some part of me thought that was a good idea at the time.